# Electron: accessing the browser window of the single instance when called a second time

Tags: electron

1. I have been able to successfully create an Electron app that links to the web app (using `window.loadUrl`).
2. I have been able to pass some command line params to the web app using `window.webContents.send ...`. On the web app, the javascript receives the parameter and updates the screen.
3. I am using (2) by opening a file (right-click on it from the directory) through file association using `process.argv[1]`. This too works.

What I would like is that if I right-click on a second file, it must be passed on to the **same electron instance**. I am having some issues for this.

I have used the recommended approach for preventing multiple instances as below:

```
...
let myWindow = null

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()

if (!gotTheLock) {
  // I do not want to quit
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
  ...
}
```

In the above logic, when the program is unable to get-the-lock, the boiler-plate code quits. That works fine, in the sense, that a second window does not open. But in my case, I would like to use the process.argv[1] of the second request and pass it to the web program of the existing instance.

I have not been successful in getting a handle to the browserWindow of the other instance. I would not want to work on multiple windows where each window would call another load of the web app. The current webapp has the ability to update multiple tabs in the same window based on different parameters. Basically, that is handled in the web app itself.

What could be the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. It starred at my face and I did not see it. Added a few logs and it helped. Something like this would be a solution.

```
...
let myWindow = null;

...

function createWindow() {
    ....
    return win;
}

function processParams(...) {
 ...
}

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()

if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
  //.. this is called the second time 
  // process any commandLine params
  processParams(...)
  ...
  });

  app.on('whenReady')
   .then(_ => {
    myWindow = createWindow();
    // this is called the first time
    // process any argv params
    processParms(...);
   });
}
```