# OAuth login in separate window/browser with Electron

Tags: authentication, oauth, callback, electron

I'm working on an Electron app connected to a backend on AWS that handles the verification and creation of the user. If it matters I'm building the app with React.

Basically the backend flow is:

- Navigates to `backend.com/oauth/login`
- Backend prepares OAuth config, redirects to the Discord.com authentication url
- User authenticates, redirects to `backend.com/oauth/callback` with the neccessary information to validate the authentication and create a user

I've got this part working. But if I would open `backend.com/oauth/login` in a separate browser window, how would I know the authentication was successful?

Are there some events I could listen to in the authentication window I've opened? Maybe let the callback redirect to `backend.com/login/successful` if the authentication was completed or otherwise `backend.com/login/failed`. This feels like such a hack but I'm way out of my expertise here.

Comment: Why do you open it in a separate browser? To have access to the user's Discord cookie/credentials? If so, then you should probably set state on the backend and then read this in your React app

Comment: Well why not? I see websites do this all the time. When I click "sign in with google" you get a popup window or a new tab. This is the same but just electron. How do you close the authentication tab/window when you're done authenticating?

Comment: Opening a new tab / new window in your Electron app is not the same as launching a new browser instance. If you launch a new browser instance, you will have access to the user's Discord credentials. If not, the user will have to type his password in your popup. You can close your own popup, but not the external browser. Different applications use different methods. It is a tradeoff between complexity and user experience. The easiest is to open the new window in your Electron app. The best one is to open the user browser and then to redirect to an URL protocol that is registered to your app.

Comment: Let's assume I then open in the users browser. How do I get the authentication result back to the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three ways to do it:

- Once the authentication is successful, you redirect the user's browser to your backend where you load the authentication data in the user state. Your React/Electron app is also connected to this backend. You must be able to match those two connections
- Once the authentication is successful, you redirect the user's browser to a custom URL protocol which is registered in the OS to open your Electron app
- Once the authentication is successful, you redirect the user's browser to a port on your running Electron app

Most good Electron applications use number 2 - but it requires that your application knows how to register an URL handler on every OS it can potentially run. Number 1 is good if you can safely match the two connections. It requires passing some form of identification. Number 3 is a hack.

Comment: #2 sounds interesting. For this project it will run only on Windows. You mean I'd redirect to something like: `myapp://login?session=the_session_cookie` ?

Comment: Yes, this is what VSCode and most of its addons use when authenticating. Check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protocol-registry

Comment: Check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150541/electron-accessing-the-browser-window-of-the-single-instance-when-called-a-seco

Comment: #3 is not always a hack because certain social networks simply do not allow specifying custom protocols as redirect URIs