# Create validation online for free ELECTRON

Tags: electron

I was making a browser in ELECTRON but I need that browser when opened to do an online check and release the use of the browser, how can I do that in Electron?

Note: When the browser is opened, I send a token online to a PHP page. I get this token, check online if it is released for use, and return an Okay flag to Electron for it to allow its use.

I haven't tried any changes yet because I don't even know where to start to do this verification

Comment: Why do you need a browser? Electron can send an HTTP request? Or you need the user's cookies?

Comment: I'm make a browser for a client with rules especifics

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70939609/oauth-login-in-separate-window-browser-with-electron/70939963#70939963